# Get url of processed image in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I need to get the URL of the processed image from TYPO3. The images are placed at a custom content element and modified by users (e.g. cropped).

I'm able to get the original file URL, but I need the processed image URL (from file_processedImages table).

Here's my TS:

```
# <------------ Speakers -------- 
tt_content.speakers = FLUIDTEMPLATE
tt_content.speakers {
file = EXT:cce/Resources/Speakers.html
variables {
    images = FILES
    images {

        references {
            table = tt_content
            fieldName = image
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {

            10 = TEXT
            10 {
                data = file:current:uid
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                wrap = |,
            }

            20 = TEXT 
            20 {
                data = file:current:publicUrl
                treatIdAsReference = 1
                wrap = |###
            }

            30 = TEXT 
            30 {
                data = file:current:title
                wrap = |,
            }

            40 = TEXT 
            40 {
                data = file:current:description
                htmlSpecialChars = 1
            }
        }       
    }   
}
```

}

I thought that the reference table is always loaded as sub on tt_content.
Which means I should be able read `publicUrl` from referenced images like this

```
data = file:current:publicUrl
treatIdAsReference = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use the FilesProcessor to get the Extbase model and use it in Fluid?
See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/#dataprocessing

Comment: Already tried that with same result, returning the original image URL, not the processed one...

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas wrote, I would also suggest to use the FilesProcessor in your FLUIDTEMPLATE:

```
tt_content.speakers = FLUIDTEMPLATE
tt_content.speakers {
file = EXT:cce/Resources/Speakers.html
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10 {
        references.fieldName = image
    }
}
```

In your fluid template you can access the public URL of the original file (not processed) or get the processed URL if any croping or maxHeight etc is applied:

```
<f:for each="{files}" as="file">
    <p>Public URL: {file.originalFile.publicUrl}</p>
    <p>Processed URL: <f:uri.image image="{file}" height="{data.imageheight}" width="{data.imagewidth}" /></p>
    <hr />
</f:for>
```

Comment: Okay, now it works with this example, so I must be a mistake on my site. kudos for Thomas. Thanks